# LINKED_LIST indexing from 0, not 1, possible?

Tags: eiffel

In eiffel, indexing usually starts from 1, not 0.

I have following 2 attributes:

```
arr: ARRAY[A]

link: LINKED_LIST[B]
```

For array, I can make its indexing starts from 0 purposely, like following:

```
arr.force (value, arr.count)
```

so that arr[0] will be readable.

However, I did similar thing to LINKED_LIST:

```
link.put_i_th (value, link.count)
```

However this gets precondition violation.

Is there any way to make LINKED_LIST indexing from 0, not 1? so that link[0] will be accessible?

I need an example if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precondition `valid_key` of `put_i_th` in `LINKED_LIST` (as well as in a more general `LIST`) is specified using a function `valid_index`. The behavior of the latter can be derived from its postcondition `Result = (i >= 1 and i <= count)`. It states that a valid index is greater than zero.

The boundaries of containers are also available as queries `lower` and `upper`. For a `LIST` the value of `lower` is a constant `1`.

From the observations above it follows that a `LIST` (and a `LINKED_LIST`) cannot have elements at index `0` (or below).

Also, unlike an `ARRAY`, where the size of the structure is controlled directly, elements to a `LIST` are added one-by-one. That's why `force` in `LIST` has no index and works like `extend` that adds a new element to the end of the structure.

Although `ARRAY` allows indexing from `0` (or any other integer value), it's considered a bad practice to use a lower index other than `1` because most containers have `lower = 1`. Only in rare cases when the code can benefit from indexes starting from something different from `1`, it might make sense to deviate from the standard convention.